# UI-router can't inject resolved object into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a list of lists and I'm trying to make a detail (individual) view for each list.  I've successfully changed the URL *and* retrieved the object from the factory but the object never makes it into the controller/view.  When I click on the link for the detail the view changes but $scope.list is undefined.  What am I doing wrong?

**Config**:

*As far as I can tell the error is in the way I am doing the resolve but this is the only thing I tried that didn't throw an error*

```
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
        .state('lists', {
            url: '/lists',
            templateUrl: 'views/lists.html',
            controller: 'ListsCtrl',
            resolve: {
                listsPromise: ['lists', function (lists){
                    console.log('LISTS State');
                    return lists.getAll();
                }]
            }
        })
        .state('list', {
            url: '/{id}',
            templateUrl: 'views/list.html',
            controller: 'ListCtrl',
            resolve: {
                list: ['$stateParams', 'lists', function($stateParams, lists){
                    return lists.getList($stateParams.id);
                }]
            },
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/lists');

}]);
```

**Factory**:

```
.factory('lists', ['$http', 
    function($http){
        var lists = {
            lists: []
        };

        lists.getAll = function(){
            $http.get('/lists').success(function(res){
                angular.copy(res, lists.lists);
            });
        };

        lists.getList = function(id){
            $http.get(id).then(function(res){
                return res.data;
            });
        };

        return lists;
}]);
```

**Controller(s)**:

*is it possible to do this with one controller?*

```
.controller('ListsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'ngDialog', 'lists',
    function($scope, $http, lists) {
    console.log("controller loaded");
    $scope.lists = lists.lists;

}])
.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http, list){
        $scope.list = list;
        console.log(list); //returns undefined
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here that I can see.

1. You are not returning a promise from either `lists.getAll()` or `lists.getList()`. Without returning a promise, the UI router doesn't know to wait for a promise to be resolved before invoking your controller. To fix it, put a `return` before the `$http` call in both.
2. Invoking the URL `id` directly in `lists.getList()` is likely wrong, since it will result in a request to a URL that is just a number, nothing else. And it will be a relative URL, too, which you probably don't want.
3. The key in the `resolve` map/object is actually the name of a *local* dependency for that controller only, so you should have that as an explicit dependency in your controller. The value of it will be whatever the promise resolves to.

To fix the last one, change your `ListCtrl` to as follows:

```
 .controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'list',
     function($scope, $http, list){
         $scope.list = list;
         console.log(list); //returns the correct thing
  }]);
```

Comment: I made these changes and now I'm getting 404 which is really strange to me. . .

Comment: 404 for what in particular? I'm guessing you mean the request for an individual list. If so, what is the URL the server is configured to respond with details of an individual list - e.g. `/lists/<id>`?

Comment: yes, 404 for the individual list.  The url is /lists/:id across the board (config, factory, and route)

Comment: Then in that case, change your `.getList()` function to have the following first line: `return $http.get('/lists/' + id).then(function (res) {`. That's what I meant by my second point - the URL is wrong.

Comment: Ah, that was it exactly.  Thank you.

Comment: @dumbname92 Don't forget to accept this answer, then (click the tick outline), and optionally upvote it.

Comment: Just accepted it, will come back to upvote when I have enough rep.  Thanks again.